# installing cuda 11.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, command-line, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I tried to install cuda 11.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 according to  Driver Version: 465.19.01, using guide installation in [the official website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&=Ubuntu&target_version=18.04&target_type=deb_local), when I finished running and tried this command  `nvcc --version`  it shows me `nvcc:not found`.

And when I tried this command  `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`  to install cuda, cuda 9.1.85 has been installed that its not desirable version. Please help me to figure out what can I do.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 18. There is a version 18.04

Comment: excuse me i meant ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Look at answers 1077061 and 1219761, and pick one installation method which meets your needs.  Both suggest you get the latest Nvidia driver from the standard repos, but 11.3 may actually need a newer version. look in the graphics-drivers PPA next, and only as a last resort, use the Nvidia supplied version.